# How to open window centered in unity desktop?

Tags: unity, window-management

Is there a way to open and/or set programs in the center of the desktop in Unity?

Answer (score 6):

Install CompizConfig Settings Manager

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Window Management -> Place Windows